# Why don't RPC get_table_rows return all rows?

Tags: rpc, apiendpoint

[I have 395 items in a table.](https://bloks.io/account/cptblackbill?loadContract=true&tab=Tables&table=treasure&account=cptblackbill&scope=cptblackbill&limit=500)

Why don't RPC get_table_rows return all items in a POST request?

I'm testing with two api endpoints: eos.dfuse.eosnation.io and api.eossweden.org

{'scope': 'cptblackbill', 'code': 'cptblackbill', 'table': 'treasure', 'json':'true', 'limit':'500'};

Test1: eos.dfuse.eosnation.io returns **249 rows**. api.eossweden.org returns **395 rows**

Test2: eos.dfuse.eosnation.io returns **307 rows**. api.eossweden.org returns **395 rows**

Test3: eos.dfuse.eosnation.io returns **294 rows**. api.eossweden.org returns **341 rows**

How can I make sure that I'm getting all items from a table located in the EOS blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

The number of RPC will return depends on the amount of time it takes to build the result set. You can get the remainder of the table by starting with an offset returned by the "more" parameter in the first query.

However, the table may change between your two queries, giving you inconsistent results.

If your table changes rapidly, you might want to use a history solution to query the blockchain instead.